# Why do we need the := symbol in golang?

Tags: go

I do understand the difference between `=` and `:=` in **golang**, my question is why do we actually need the `:=`? Couldn't the compiler figure out on its own that a variable was not yet defined? Is it just about readability?

Comment: The compiler could in some cases, *but that would mask bugs*. Forcing the developer to be explicit about their intent provides clues that allow better feedback.

Comment: Compiler could not do that in every single case reliable for sure. https://play.golang.org/p/x7XmY6_-3X You cannot tell whether `:=` or `=` is intended.

Comment: (And in general, "why did the designers of language X decide to do Y?" questions either have a canonical answer somewhere (because said designer wrote up a rationale) -- in which case it can be found by Google -- or they don't, in which case questions on the subject turn into a bunch of speculation, guesswork, and opinions. Speculation and opinion tend to be frowned on here, at least when the latter can't be backed by something concrete).

Comment: Yes zerkms you are right. Why don't you write your answer elaborating the example so I can select your answer? I would remove and add the : in the func so you can show that the results are different.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you can shadow outer-scope variables in an inner scope, such as a closure or loop; the compiler cannot infer purely based on whether the variable existed before or not. Having to explicitly define variables also helps to reduce defects which are commonplace in languages like PHP and JavaScript that allow you to just `foo = bar` without any consideration of whether `foo` has been defined. That kind of loose compilation paves over common mistakes *like typos* such that they're no longer caught at compile time, they show up as "weird behavior" at runtime, which is much, much harder to track down and fix.

Comment: I like zerkms comment more but since he hasn't posted an answer yet I'll set yours as the answer since it is also correct.

Comment: It's the same answer, but demonstrated instead of explained. That play example is what I'm talking about w/r/t shadowing variables from an outer scope.

Comment: It is the "same" answer indeed (a better one tbh: with more details)

Comment: I don't know if it's better, I usually prefer explanation + example but didn't have time.